# AWS Lambda: how to add S3Event trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda NET 6 function. It was created in VS2022
with template using 2 entry points

```
LambdaEntryPoint
LocalEntryPoint
```

to run in AWS or in a local environment.

How can I add S3 Event trigger to the lambda?

Comment: I suspect the template you have is intended for a WEB API. To trigger a Lambda using the S3 trigger, use the standard AWS Lambda Project template.

Comment: I develop Lambda NET6 ->RDS.  Web API is most suitable. No any other ways to use S3 events in Lambda Web API function?